# Проблема с блоком который следет за курсором

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

Проблема в том что когда вывести курсор за окно браузера появляется горизонтальный или вертикальный скролл. Как от этого избавиться?
ЗЫ
Страница должна скроллится нормально. Overflow:hidden, height:100vh не подходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Codepen - Пример взял отсюда](https://codepen.io/quentindigital/pen/BapazMy)

Для примера вот код

HTML

```
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900);
body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; 
    width : 100%;  
    margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
  border-radius: 50%;  
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;
   
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 30; 
  });
    
  setInterval(function(){
    xp += ((mouseX - xp)/6);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp)/6);
    $("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});
  }, 20);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятна суть вопроса, но смею предположить, что вам надо, что бы скролы не появлялись. Делаеться это так:

```
body, html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
  width : 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Появляються, они поскольку размера круга вылазят за область видимости.

Comment: Тогда пропадет скролл на странице

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Оберните элемент в какой-то div и задайте ему значения CSS  ' position: relative; max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;'

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось достичь такого поведения, обернув элемент в контейнер.

```
<div id='container'>
  <span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

И задав следующие стили

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```